# PYTHONPATH ok in shell, does not load in python

Tags: python, bash, macos, bsd

My Mac mini hard drive crashed recently and I had to reinstall everything. Current MacOS is 10.14.6 (Mojave). I have also installed Anaconda's python distro (command line installation). In my shell:

```
echo $PYTHONPATH
/Users/administrator/Dropbox/premalstuff/pythonclass
```

However my python distro does not inherit the $PYTHONPATH:

```
python -c "import sys; print(sys.path)"
['', '/Users/administrator/anaconda3/lib/python37.zip', '/Users/administrator/anaconda3/lib/python3.7', '/Users/administrator/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload', '/Users/administrator/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages', '/Users/administrator/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aeosa']
```

Any suggestions for troubleshooting are highly appreciated.

Comment: Try `export PYTHONPATH=/Users/administrator/Dropbox/premalstuff/pythonclass`.

Comment: You probably didn't read my question carefully enough. The shell already defines that variable properly. The python interpreter isn't aware of it though.

Comment: And what does `python -c "import os; print(os.environ['PYTHONPATH'])"` output?

Comment: You have an attitude.

Comment: python -c "import os; print(os.environ['PYTHONPATH'])"

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/administrator/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/os.py", line 679, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'PYTHONPATH'